# Edit JSONB data in textarea form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB field on my model users are able to CRUD via my API. This all works fine.

I'd like to be able to give internal staff/admin users the ability to edit the JSON settings object via a textarea form field. (The users are tech-savvy and will know how to write valid JSON.)

In the Rails UI, when I open the record, the form loads the JSON settings into the textarea fine, but on save the entire object is effectively wiped.

I can see the settings param is sent:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bla_bla_bla", "users_notification"=>{"user_id"=>"48", "report_id"=>"2", "status"=>"1", "frequency"=>"1", "settings"=>"{\"threshold\"=>\"50\"}"}, "commit"=>"Update Users notification", "id"=>"18"}
```

and I am 99% sure I have whitelisted the params correctly:

```
def users_notification_params
  params.require(:users_notification).permit(
    :user_id,
    :report_id,
    :status,
    :frequency,
    :settings,
    settings: [:threshold, :products, :avg_sales]
  )
end
```

However, when I output the users_notification_params with puts, I can see that settings is nil:

```
{"user_id"=>"48", "report_id"=>"2", "status"=>"1", "frequency"=>"1", "settings"=>nil}
```

I figured I need to parse the settings param so set about putting a before_action callback in place, but when I output the users_notification_params I still see `"settings"=>nil`, so I have nothing to parse.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is that Rails does not automatically parse the JSON string into a hash and you're trying to whitelist a hash. Try removing `settings: [:threshold, :products, :avg_sales]`. You then have to parse the JSON in the model or in the controller.

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  def settings=(val)
    if val.is_a?(String)
      begin 
        super JSON.parse(val)
      rescue JSON::ParserError
        errors[:settings].add('is not valid JSON')
        super
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In general it seems like a pretty clunky way to do something that can be done by using separate inputs for each setting. You can use `store_accessor` for this.

Comment: Thanks Max, I'll have a closer look at store_accessor

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the admin the posibility to change a textfield you could give the form extra fields for your settings:

```
<%= form_with(model: users_notification, local: true) do |form| %>
   <%= form.fields_for(:settings) do |sf| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= sf.label :threshold %>
        <%= sf.number_field :threshold %>
      </div>
   <% end %>

   ...

<% end %>
```

With this the params will be like

```
{"users_notification"=>{"settings"=>{"threshold"=>"1"}}
```

This will work with your `permit`.

Comment: The settings will vary a fair bit as new types of users_notification are introduced so this was meant to be a catch-all setup. But I think you could be right and even though I said they will be able to enter valid JSON, I can guarantee someone won't! I'll give this a try.